# How to pass model object to img tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a foreach in my view which loops an object who has a field Image. Now I want that image to show. So I want to put the image name in an html img tag.

View:

```
@foreach (var item in LstBagels)
            {
                @Html.Hidden("TxtId", item.BagelId);
                <div id="bagel">
                    <div id="bagel-image">
                        <!--<img src="~/App_Data/images/" + @Html.LabelFor(m => item.Image) + ".jpg" />-->
                    </div>
                </div>    
            }
```

The images are stored in the App_Data/images map. And in the database I just store the name like "nobagel".

**EDIT:**

With the given solutions I get following html:

```
<img src="/App_Data/images/nobagel.jpg" >
```

This seems correct but the image doesn't show.

**EDIT 2:**

I am using this now in my View:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format(Server.MapPath("~")  + "App_Data\\images\\{0}.jpg", item.Image))" alt="" />
```

Which gives this html output:

```
<img alt="" src="C:\Users\stage\Desktop\BestelBagels\BestelBagels\BestelBagels\App_Data\images\nobagel.jpg">
```

If I just copy paste the src to my browser I can see the image.

Comment: Do you actually have the image in that folder in the project?

Comment: Don't forget to change the `src` back to website relative path, it won't work if you leave the machine path when you publish the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, You don't need to use `@Html.LabelFor`

```
 <img src="~/App_Data/images/@(item.Image).jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Url.Content` to ensure the URL is properly qualified:

```
<img src='@Url.Content(String.Format("~/App_Data/images/{0}.jpg", item.Image))' />
```

Comment: Hmm. I get url loading failed.

Comment: Are you sure `item.Image` is just the name without the extension?

Comment: Yes I just checked in my database. If I inspect the html with firebug its correct but It doesn't show the image

Comment: Interesting, does the constructed URL look correct in firebug?

Comment: Yes it does. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Html.LabelFor`, use only `item.Image`. (if `item.Image` is the file name)

```
<img src="/App_Data/images/@(item.Image).jpg" />
```

Comment: Thx, this seems to work. Only got 1 problem that the image doesn't show but the name is correct.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter, in fact I dont get the html output if I remove the tilda.

Comment: Well, my best guess is that your image is not in that location, or has a different name. Check for capitalization or typos. Try to check it using the exact same string, in a controller, using `new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/images"), item.Image + ".jpg").Exists`

Comment: @NanouPonette - I really don't know - did you forget to remove the html comments? `<!-- -->`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@foreach (var item in LstBagels)
{
    @Html.Hidden("TxtId", item.BagelId);
    <div id="bagel">
        <div id="bagel-image">
            <img src="@string.Format("~/App_Data/images/{0}.jpg", item.Image)" alt="" />
            @item.Image
        </div>
    </div>    
}
```